# Duplicates in array of numbers failing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following function to check for duplicates;

```
function hasDuplicates(array) {
  return (new Set(array)).size !== array.length;
}
```

I use this to check if someone has not provided two of the same items to sell from his or her inventory, cause we won't allow him or her getting twice the amount of money he or her should.

It worked for a while but then I think someone who meant harm came in and breached it somehow. I've been testing for a while now and found that I can bypass this sytem by having my array like the following (ids of my inventories);

```
var array = [312, 329, 932]; //normal > should bypass
var array = [333, 333, 333]; //not normal > can't bypass
```

but then if you do this it allows you to bypass;

```
var array = [333, '333/', '333//'];
```

is there any way I can solve this quickily?

**Edit**
Database query that looks up the data anyways even if its provided as 333// strings.

```
database.query('SELECT * FROM `inventories` WHERE `id` = ' + database.pool.escape(id), function(err, row){
```

Comment: `333` is not the same as `'333/'`, so they're not duplicates.

Comment: You're probably using `parseInt()` to parse the values at some point, and `parseInt()` does not complain about trailing non-numeric characters. Use `Math.floor(+n)` instead (assuming you really do want integers).

Comment: @Barmar I found that out the hard way. As they strings like that are working when they are looked up in my database.

Comment: Then there's something really weird about your database.

Comment: @Pointy check my updated database query in the question. is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: I don't know what `database.pool.escape()` does but the fact is that a database that thinks the numeric value 333 is equal to the *string* value `"333/"` strikes me as strange.

Comment: @Pointy its just a regular escape from MySQL. I also logged it in the console and it just showed up as 333/

Comment: @Pointy When MySQL coerces a string to a number, it ignores trailing non-numeric values, similar to `parseInt()`.

Comment: @Barmar wow. I'm going to go hug my Postgresql installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 array.every(n => Number.isInteger(n))
```

Just ensure that everything is a number in the array.

Comment: Can I just do if(array.every(n => Number.isInteger(n)))? and if so all the numbers are integers, if not return false?

Comment: Right, thats what its doing

Comment: It's so easy to overlook in my case, such a catastrophe. Thanks, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following with hash, 
and use `regex` to remove the special characters and leave it with a number only, (casting it to `Number` is also recommended).

```js
var array = ['333//', 212, '333/'];  

var hash = {};

array.forEach(num => {

 if(!Number.isInteger(num)) {
   num = Number(num.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''));
 }
 
 if(!hash[num]) {
    hash[num] = num;
 }
})

var newArray = Object.values(hash);
console.log(newArray);
```